# jquery input form validation

Tags: jquery, validation, input

Lets assume that I have a `<table>` (not `<form>` !) with 2 input fields.

```
   <table>
       <tr>
           <td><input type="text" name="aadress" /></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td><input type="text" name="telefon" /></td>
       </tr>
   <table>
```

Is is possible to validate the whole table with `jquery .validate()`? Or cai I use it with `input` fields?
The main point is that I **do not have a submit button**.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a button to validate your fields, you can use JQs *".keyup( handler(eventObject) )"* event function. You can use the following code to validate your fields.

```
$('.myTable').keyup(function(e){
    if (e.target.name == 'address' && e.target.value.length > 5) {
        console.log(e.target.value);
        $(e.target).css({ 'border-color': '#25E01B', 'border-style':'solid' });
        //do more stuff
    }
    if (e.target.name == 'telefon' && e.target.value.length > 5) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
        $(e.target).css({ 'border-color': '#25E01B', 'border-style': 'solid' });
        //do more stuff
    }
});
```

for

```
<table class="mytable">
       <tr>
           <td><input type="text" name="address" /></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td><input type="text" name="telefon" /></td>
       </tr>
<table>
```